# MouseEvent outside the application window (JAVA)

Tags: java, mouseevent, mouseclick-event

I am aware that this question has been asked before but I couldn't find an answer so I wanted to ask again. Is there any way I can detect the times when the mouse is clicked outside the window? I am trying to write a program which records the coordinates where the mouse is clicked and repeats them. So far I can achieve my goal by giving the coordinates manually to robot.mousemove method. And I can get the point where the mouse stands withgetPointerInfo.getLocation but I only want to get the points where the mouse is clicked, not every point where the mouse stands. Is there any way for that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Java at it's own, because of its security settings. You'll have to use an external library, e.g. written in JNI.